# jsf selectBooleanCheckbox value set only once

Tags: windows, maven, jsf

In my WebApplication I got a very strange issue for selectBooleanCheckbox (and other components) on Windows10 with Firefox and Edge ("IE").

What I use:
JSF: v2.1
JDK: 1.7.0_79
Maven 3.3.9
jetty-maven-plugin: 7.5.4.v20111024

Relevant code in my xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
...
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{configurationController.enableSignature}" id="enableSignatureChkBox">
            <f:ajax render="configurationForm"/>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Starting my WebApplication on Windows10, I get the following with Firefox and Edge:

1. first click on "enableSignature": works
2. second click on "enableSignature": doesn't work. Checkbox remains checked, no value set behind. Independent how many tries...
3. Press F5
4. Click works again **once** (then same as after 1. )

If I test with Chrome, everything works fine!

Also:

- If I start my project under Windows7, it works fine with every browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome)
- No problems either if I start it up under Linux

All browser are uptodate.

Where is the bug?

Comment: Press F12 in Firefox. Can you see any error in the console when the selection not working?

Comment: JSF 2.1 is an api version, not an implementation and its version. Mojarra 2.1.x or MyFaces 2.1.x is...